# Relation "table name" doesn't exist postgresql

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I'm doing a query in java, i have java and posgres connected with the driver 9.3-1102-jdbc41

This is my query: `query = "SELECT * FROM" +"\"users\" "+ " where user="+"'"+name+"'"+"and pass =" +"'"+pass+"'";`

when I run it, this error appears:

Relation "users name" doesn't exist

Here and in others sites a possible solution is checking the quotes or the capital letters. 
But I´m sure about the capital letters and this is what I tried:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM" +"\"users\" "+ " where user="+"'"+name+"'"+"and pass =" +"'"+pass+"'";

query = "SELECT * FROM users  where user="+"'"+name+"'"+"and pass =" +"'"+pass+"'";

query = "SELECT * FROM" +"\"sysmar.users\" "+ " where user="+"'"+name+"'"+"and pass =" +"'"+pass+"'";
```

Error relation users does not exist

```
"SELECT * FROM users  where user="+name+"and pass =" +pass;
```

syntax error near to pass

Thanks in advance for your answers and time

Comment: No space before `and pass`

Comment: In your first query there are blanks missing  i think: `query = "SELECT * FROM " +"\"users\" "+ " where user="+"'"+name+"'"+" and pass =" +"'"+pass+"'";` One blank after `from` and one before `and pass`

Comment: Try looking in the database with some tool first. That lists all tables for instance. First guess: you are in the wrong database scheme. Tools: NetBeans IDE, Toad e.a.

Comment: `user` is a reserved word in PostgreSQL and standard SQL. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.3/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html - P.S. What helps too, removing first a large part of the SQL, like the entire WHERE part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PostgreSQL you shouldn't need to put quotes around the table name unless it's a reserved keyword. `Users` isn't a keyword, but `user` just so happens to be one of them.

Your query is hard enough to read with the extra concatenation operations and spacing issues. Perhaps there is a syntax error and you just need to clean it up:

```
q = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE \"user\" = '" + name + "' AND pass = '" + pass + "'";
```

You want the final evaluated string to look like (for example):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE "user" = 'cory' AND pass = '12345';
```

But as others have mentioned, you should also switch to using prepared statements. This code is probably vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @JuanCamiloMejia: Updated. You were trying to quote `users` but instead you should be quoting `user`.

Comment: I tried this 
`query = "SELECT * FROM users where name="+"'"+name+"'"+" and pass=" +"'"+pass+"'";`

and this

`query = "SELECT * FROM "+"'"+"users"+"'"+ "where name="+"'"+name+"'"+" and pass=" +"'"+pass+"'";`

but nothing changes

Comment: But now you've changed your `user` column name to `name`. Which is it? Also, you don't need to quote your table or column names unless they are reserved words. The only one you had before was the *column* `user`.

Comment: Im sorry for the mistake, now I tried 

`"SELECT * FROM users where 'user'="+name+"and pass=" +pass;` That shows syntax  error near to pass.

and I tried this also:
`"SELECT * FROM users where 'user'="+name+"and 'pass'=" +pass;`
But realation error appears

Comment: Use the first one but keep the single quotes around the name and password values just like I have in my answer and double quotes around the column names. You want the final query look something like `SELECT * FROM users where "user" = 'cory' and pass = '12345'`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
"SELECT * FROM users  where \"user\" ='"+name+"'and pass ='" +pass+"'";
```

But it's harmful for `sql injection`. See `PreparedStatements`.

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword and should be quoted.

Comment: yap. Didn't noticed. Edited @Cory

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't concatenate variables with SQL queries, you are becoming vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) then. You better be using [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) which will allow you to write queries in more readable and secure fashion.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = ? AND pass = ?";
PreparedStatement query = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
query.setString(1, name);
query.setString(2, password);
ResultSet result = query.executeQuery();
```